# what is the time complexity of this code?

Tags: c, big-o, time-complexity

```
int i = 1;
while (i < n/2)
{
    i = i * 2;
    int j = i;

    while (j > 1)
        --j;
}
```

Comment: Uh, WTF? This whole thing could be a single expression on `i`.

Comment: As the function is stated here it'll not run as n isn't declared, so not very long!

Comment: This is not a homework site. At least tell us what difficulties you're having with it.

Comment: n as mentioned in books is a huge number!

Comment: its not related to homework , i saw that in book , they mentioned that func running time is O(n) without explanation .

Comment: Ok, so you are not talking about running time (that is machine dependant) but rather algorithm complexity. You also don't have any function in this post. You know, asking the right question is the first step to get the answer. In some cases, asking the question in the right terms also make the answer obvious.

Comment: if it is not HW, why the downvote? it does not compile because it is a theoretical question.

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting.  In future, please make sure you replace tabs in the code with spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`O(n)`:

outer loop runs `logn` times, in each iteration: i=1,2,4,8,...n/4 (entrance values)

inner loops runs `2*i` times (entrance values)

so at overall you get: `2+4+8+...+n/2 = n-2 = O(n)`

Comment: I think this is correct assuming that n is a power of 2 in the first place. If n <> m^2 then its a little more messy

Comment: @Jon: actually there is no mess, in any case, the algorithm will finish iterating when i = n/4 (entrance to last iteration) (and not n/2 as I previously wrote... edited). and is still O(n)

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop executes twice on the first iteration, then four times, then eight times, etc.

So you need to figure out where the sum terminates:

```
2 + 4 + 8 + ...
```

and then work out how to evaluate it (clue: *geometric series*).